# Better bloom filter in python

Tags: python-3.x, redis, bloom-filter

I have found different bloom filter packages available in python. But I am bit confused which one is better to use.

[redis-bloom-filter](https://pypi.org/project/redis-bloom-filter/) vs [bloom-filter](https://pypi.org/project/bloom-filter/)

I have a speculation that `bloom-filter` will be faster than `redis-bloom-filter` due to network latency in the later.

My use case - I am building a scraper where my URL is going to be same but the payload for every search will differ. For filtering I am hashing few values in the payload and use them in bloom filter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you tag Redis? Do you want to you Redis (RedisBloom), or are you looking for a stand-alone Python implementation?

Comment: @LiorKogan My scrapers are going to be running from different servers. So I am considering RedisBloom as a single instance for the bloomfilter. But I want to check is there any way of implementing standalone bloom filter for such distributed design. if yes, I want to compare the functionalities as pros and cons

Comment: pros/cons are subjective. I don't think that your question is clear.